# How fast is the data center asynchronous replication?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

If I have two data centers - one purely only for disaster recovery - and I do all of my writes with LOCAL_QUORUM to the primary DC. How up-to-date can I expect the data on the disaster-recovery DC?

Comment: http://grokbase.com/t/cassandra/user/165k9vcq9j/replication-lag-between-data-center

Comment: @undefined_variable Thanks. But are there any metrics out there that show the expected throughput/latency for asynchronous writes between datacenters in practice?